# Entity Framework 5 built in Database Initializers and Seed method in Code First

Tags: entity-framework, web-config

I'm using EF 5 and trying to figure out how different built in database initializers are calling the Seed() method. 
These are my questions:

**1. What is a good initializer for seeding the database only when the model changes?

 2. How to configure each db initializer in web.config?**

Clarifications for my first question:
So far I know that these are the built in database initializers of EF 5:

- MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion
- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways

My problem is in understanding when the Seed method of each of these initializers is called. I've looked inside the EntityFramework dll and checked the code of each of these initializer's InitializeDatabase() method to check when each is called. This is what I found:

**MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion**: I couldn't find out when the seed method is called but from my tests it is called every time the app runs, no matter if there are changes in the model.
**CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**: I could find that the Seed method is called only when creating the database. If it exists, no seed should be done.
**DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges**: It seems that InitializeDatabase method calls Seed() every time, no matter if the model changed or not. The call is outside the if(context.Dabase.Exists()) check. 
**DropCreateDatabaseAlways**: It is obvious that this will always call Seed method.

Is this correct? If so, it doesn't seem like I could restrict seeding to the case in which the model changes and I should probably write a custom initializer.

Regarding my 2nd question, I know how to configure the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion but i find it difficult to write as I don't know the meaning of this declaration (especially the '2 part - is it the value of an enum, in which case how should I figure what is the corresponding number of other initializers?):

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<contexts>
  <context type="Digidata.MP.Data.ObjectContext, Digidata.MP.Data">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Digidata.MP.Data.ObjectContext,  Digidata.MP.Data], [Digidata.MP.Data.Migrations.Configuration, Digidata.MP.Data]], EntityFramework"/>
  </context>
</contexts>
```

Where can I find an explanation of how to declare the built in initializers in a config file?

Comment: In order to answer your first question there is a crucial information missing: do you intend to use database migrations or not?

Comment: Nope. I don't want migrations.